# How can I access a property defined in a constructor of a class inside a method of the same class in Javascript without using this keyword?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, eslint

I have eslint checks configured for my code and it's throwing me the following error for the following code:

Error :

> error  Unexpected 'this'  no-invalid-this

Code eg:

```js
class A {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  methodA = () => {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

How can I fix the code so that it follows eslint rules?

Comment: This is valid code

Comment: I keep getting the above error, I just added "parser": "babel-eslint", in my .eslintrc file

Comment: It does the job, the code is valid but it's not passing the eslint rules.

Comment: is it in strict mode? or did you setup `"parserOptions": { "sourceType": "module" }` in eslint config?

Comment: I have setup "parserOptions": { "sourceType": "module" }  in my .eslintrc file

Comment: well, not a lot info TBH. How did you end up with error. Is in IDE (editor) or CLI (command line).

Comment: It's in CLI, I did my research to fix the error but was just not able to find anything on the net

Comment: instead of assigning a arrow function to a property, declaring methods like methodA(name) did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of assigning a arrow function to a property, declaring methods like `methodA(name)` did the job.